# Should I use or avoid independent-density pixels in android animated game development?

Tags: android, graphics, density-independent-pixel

My question is:
Does the DIP "engine" kill performance?
How it would perform for bitmap sprites and how for drawing polygons?

If I should avoid this: is it any good guide how to handle multiple physical resolutions and densities?

Comment: As long as the final scaling is [hardware] accelerated, I'm not sure how it'd kill performance...

Answer (score 0):

Deep calculation within layout xml files is in the compile time, not in the runtime. So don't worry about the performance.